# Reading comment from XML using DOM parser

Tags: java, xml-parsing

When i try to read Comment's from XML file, Comment's from both the element are printing twice, when it pass through the loop. it should print first element comment in first iteration and second element comment in next iteration. If it is not clear, I have attached expected Output and Actual output for reference.

XML Code:

```
<shipments>
  <shipment id="011">
    <department>XXXX</department>
    <!--  Product: XXXXX-->
  </shipment>   
</shipments>
```

Code:

```
public class Main {
   public static void main(String[] args) throws SAXException,
    IOException, ParserConfigurationException, XMLStreamException {

    DocumentBuilderFactory factory = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();

      // Ignores all the comments described in the XML File
      factory.setIgnoringComments(false);
    DocumentBuilder builder = factory.newDocumentBuilder();

    Document doc = builder.parse(new File("Details.xml"));
    doc.getDocumentElement().normalize(); 

    NodeList ShipmentList = doc.getElementsByTagName("shipment");

    for (int i = 0; i < ShipmentList.getLength(); i++)
    {
     Node node = ShipmentList.item(i);
             if (node.getNodeType() == Node.ELEMENT_NODE)
     {
           Element eElement = (Element) node; 
        XMLStreamReader xr = XMLInputFactory.newInstance().createXMLStreamReader(new FileInputStream("shipmentDetails_1.xml")); 
         while (xr.hasNext()) {
             if (xr.next() == XMLStreamConstants.COMMENT) {                                     
                 String comment = xr.getText();         
                 System.out.print("Comments: ");
                 System.out.println(comment);

             } }


     }
    }
}

}
```

**Expected Output:**

COMMENTS :
Product : Laptop

COMMENTS :
Product : Mobile Phone

**Output What i am getting:**

Comments: Product:Laptop
Comments: Product:Mobile Phone

Comments: Product:Laptop
Comments: Product:Mobile Phone

Comment: Hi @Vassan, can you please clarify your question? What is the problem? What output are you expecting vs what are you receiving? Why isn't the text `Product:Mobile Phone` part of the XML structure?

Comment: *"I don't have any clue about how to print [...] comment"* Similar to how you're printing elements, you write code to check for `node.getNodeType() == Node.COMMENT_NODE`, cast to a `Comment`, and print the value of `getData()`.

Comment: *"I don't have any clue about how to print XML declaration"* Then you should **read the documentation**, i.e. the javadoc of [`Document`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/org/w3c/dom/Document.html), which lists the following methods: `getXmlEncoding()`, `getXmlStandalone()`, `  getXmlVersion()`

Comment: @Vasan, you should put your `while` loop for printing the comments _outside_ of the `for` loop. It seems that the comments are read all at once by the parser as _unstructured data_. If you want to read the comments as structured data you will need to include them in the XML structure (_i.e._ they need an element tag!)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get the values from the XML declaration, call the following methods on the [`Document`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/org/w3c/dom/Document.html):

- [`getXmlEncoding()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/org/w3c/dom/Document.html#getXmlEncoding--) - An attribute specifying, as part of the [XML declaration](http://www.w3.org/TR/2004/REC-xml-20040204#NT-XMLDecl), the encoding of this document. This is `null` when unspecified or when it is not known, such as when the `Document` was created in memory.
- [`getXmlStandalone()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/org/w3c/dom/Document.html#getXmlStandalone--) - An attribute specifying, as part of the [XML declaration](http://www.w3.org/TR/2004/REC-xml-20040204#NT-XMLDecl), whether this document is standalone. This is `false` when unspecified.
- [`getXmlVersion()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/org/w3c/dom/Document.html#getXmlVersion--) - An attribute specifying, as part of the [XML declaration](http://www.w3.org/TR/2004/REC-xml-20040204#NT-XMLDecl), the version number of this document. If there is no declaration and if this document supports the "XML" feature, the value is `"1.0"`.

---

**UPDATED**

To find and print comments inside the `<shipment>` element, iterate the child nodes of the element and look for nodes of type [`COMMENT_NODE`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/org/w3c/dom/Node.html#COMMENT_NODE), cast it to a [`Comment`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/org/w3c/dom/Comment.html), and print the value of [`getData()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/org/w3c/dom/CharacterData.html#getData--).

```
for (Node child = node.getFirstChild(); child != null; child = child.getNextSibling()) {
    if (child.getNodeType() == Node.COMMENT_NODE) {
        Comment comment = (Comment) child;
        System.out.println("COMMENTS : " + comment.getData());
    }
}
```

*To clarify:* The `node` used here is from the question code. You can also use `eElement` instead of `node`. Makes no difference.

Comment: Thanks @andreas. I was able to get the Encoding and Version.For Comment , I tried as you mentioned. But it didnt work

Comment: I did it in different way. I have posted Expected output and output which i am getting

Comment: @Vasan Answer was updated to correct find comments belonging to a given `<shipment>` element.

Comment: I believe this answer is correct. But need to add that in the answer, Node child = node.getFirstChild() is used. 'node' there is really from node that was type casted to Element in previous statement. There is no need to read the xml again (especially inside the loop) and 'xr' should be dropped

Answer (score -1):

To obtain the XML Declaration and comments, I would suggest loading the file as a text file and parsing it via regular expressions. For example:

```
    String file = new String(Files.readAllBytes(Paths.get("shipmentDetails_1.xml")), StandardCharsets.UTF_8);

    Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("<!--([\\s\\S]*?)-->");
    Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(file);
    while (matcher.find()) {
        System.out.println("COMMENTS: " + matcher.group(1));
    }

    Pattern pattern2 = Pattern.compile("<\\?xml([\\s\\S]*?)\\?>");
    Matcher matcher2 = pattern2.matcher(file);
    while (matcher2.find()) {
        System.out.println("DECLARATION: " + matcher2.group(1));
    }
```

Comment: Downvoted for suggesting "parsing [XML] via regular expressions". As bad as [parsing HTML](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1732454/5221149).

Comment: @Andreas, I agree with you in the general case, but regular expressions can be a handy (and very quick) solution for certain edge cases. I probably should have read the documentation, but in this case I wasn't sure if it was even possible to get the parser to read comments. But from your answer it's clear that it's possible.